# Gatsby contains invalid WIN32 path characters

Tags: gatsby

I have some problems with seting routing in production version(gatsby build)
this is what pops up in console:

```
error Building static HTML failed

See our docs page on debugging HTML builds for help https://gatsby.app/debug-html

       5 |          function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
       6 | 
    >  7 |                  // Check if module is in cache
         | ^
       8 |                  if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
       9 |                          return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
      10 |                  }


      WebpackError: C:\Users\Elephate2018\Desktop\lllllliililiililii\GATSBY3\GatsbyPage\public\:news\:title contains invali  d WIN32 path characters.
```

In development version everything is worrking good but when i try gatsby build production version(gatsby build) i have this error.

code from routing

src/routes/index.js

```
const path = require('path')

const routes = {
  home: {
    path: '/',
    component: path.resolve(__dirname, 'home.js')
  },
  UsaToday: {
    path: '/UsaToday',
    component: path.resolve(__dirname, 'UsaToday.js')
  },
  Time: {
    path: '/Time',
    component: path.resolve(__dirname, 'Time.js')
  },
  Details: {
    path: '/:news/:title',
    component: path.resolve(__dirname, 'details.js')
  }
}

// Same keys as 'routes', but the value is only the path.
const paths = Object.keys(routes).reduce((acc, route) => {
  acc[route] = routes[route].path
  return acc
}, {})

module.exports =  { routes, paths }
```

gatsby-node.js

```
const { routes } = require('./src/routes')

exports.createPages = ({ actions }) => {
  console.log(actions)
  const { createPage } = actions
  Object.keys(routes).forEach(route => createPage(routes[route]))
}
```

Comment: Gatsby create a file for each page you generate. You generate a `/:news/:title` url but Windows doesn't allow the `:` symbol in path. Would you like to have `/:news/:title` in the url ? It looks like these parameters should be replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gatsby doesn't accept parameters in path like that when generating static pages — you'd need to loop through a list of data & generate the paths themselves. Checkout the [`createPage`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#createPages) docs for an example.

Or alternatively, you have to set up those paths on the client side — in which case check out the docs for Gatsby's browser API, perhaps the [`onRouteUpdate hook`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onRouteUpdate) is what you're looking for.